# mysterious IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, split, trim, indexoutofrangeexception

Visual Studio throws an IndexOutOfRangeException inside this function:

```
public static string ExtractString(string path, string startString, char endChar)
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path);

    /*at this line*/return content.Split(new string[] { startString }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(endChar)[0].Trim();
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: the exception is straight forward. you are accessing an index which is not available or not existing or more the the length of your array.

Comment: Instead of throwing your hands up in dismay, find out where the error is.  Break the code up into multiple lines that do one thing each instead of a single line that does everything.  It will then be easy to see where the issue is based on what line it breaks at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a strange way of doing it, but I tested with some sample input of my own and it works okay under expected circumstances.

The problem occurs when `startString` is not found, because the resulting array from the first `string.Split` will contain a single element (the original input string). When you attempt to split the 2nd element on `endChar`, there is no 2nd element to find, and that is your exception.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but this will do the job, returning `null` if either `startString` or `endChar` cannot be found:

```
public static string ExtractString(string content, string startString, char endChar)
{
    int i, j;

    i = content.IndexOf(startString);

    if (i == -1)
        return null;
    else
        i += startString.Length; // Start at char after startString

    j = content.IndexOf(endChar);

    if (j == -1)
        return null;

    return content.Substring(i, j - i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, without your hint I never would have checked the text file again anytime soon. The content got somehow deleted. Obviously the error is gone now, that I repaired the file. And thank you for the rearranged function.